# Unable to get an opensearch Curl request since running the service with systemctl

Tags: curl, systemd, opensearch, ubuntu-22.04, graylog

I am in the process of installing a Graylog server on Ubuntu 22.04, i have been following the official documentation and so far i have installed MongoDB and Opensearch-2.0.1. I installed Opensearch using tarball (https://opensearch.org/docs/2.0/install-and-configure/install-opensearch/tar/) and it is currently running without any security plugins although it is ready to go when needed. To verify it was working i opened a terminal and ran a Curl command and also opened a web browser which verified the details i want.

The next step was to run opensearch as a server with systemd. Once i did that i ran:
`

```
 sudo systemctl daemon-reload ` 
`sudo systemctl enable opensearch.service` 
`sudo systemctl start opensearch` 
`sudo systemctl status opensearch`
```

the last of which verifed that opensearch was now running as a service, but since then if I try to use a Curl command or a web browser it is unable to connect. The firewall is inactive so it is not blocking any traffic, I am at a loss.

I appreciate any light on this and I`m happy to answer any questions.

Thank you

`curl -X GET http://localhost:9200 curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200 after 0 ms: Connection refused`
Created a non root user to run the service.
Checked firewall rules
Changed network host from private ip to 0.0.0.0
Checked logs
`sudo netstat -tlnp | grep 9200`
to check for listening processes but there`s nothing listening to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, the crux of the problem appears to be permission issues when opensearch is running as a sservice. these are the steps I did to solve it:

This is the config for the opensearch.service file:

> [Unit] Description=OpenSearch After=network.target
>
> [Service] Type=simple User=matt Group=matt
> WorkingDirectory=/home/matt/opensearch-2.0.1/bin
> Environment=OPENSEARCH_HOME=/home/matt/opensearch-2.0.1
> Environment=OPENSEARCH_JAVA_HOME=/home/matt/opensearch-2.0.1/jdk
> ExecStart=/home/matt/opensearch-2.0.1/bin/opensearch -d Restart=always
> LimitNOFILE=65535 PermissionsStartOnly=true
>
> [Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target

Next is the changing the permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R u+w /path/to/opensearch-2.0.1
sudo chown -R opensearch:opensearch /hpath/to/opensearch-2.0.1/logs
sudo chown -R $user:group /path/to/opensearch-2.0.1/data
sudo chmod -R u+w /path/to/opensearch-2.0.1/data
```

If opensearch is running in the foreground or in daemonised mode it will need to be stopped before running systemctl.

```
pfkill opensearch
```

Now to run opensearch:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable opensearch.service
sudo systemctl start opensearch.service
sudo systemctl status opensearch.service
curl http://localhost:9200
```

Feel free to post any errors you may be getting in this thread and I will try to help.